# Allocation from a central stock in Pandas

Tags: pandas

I am struggling with creating an allocation algorithm against multiple demand.

eg: consider 2 banks operating in multiple cities. For each bank in each city there  are available funds that can be disbursed based on demand coming from multiple customers. Demand is catered to in a FIFO fashion. And post disbursement the available funds are reduced by the amount already given out.
A simplified version of the problem is:

[image]

Comment: So you want to iterate through your main table and determine a value for the allocation column? At the same time you should store the capacity in each bank in each city in a dictionary (or second dataframe) that you update each time you allocate funds to a customer.